# How can I build a porch enclosure?

Tags: brick, exterior

[image]

I'm looking to take on this project myself, I want to enclose my porch.  It's roughly 2x5 metres, and 8 feet high and is part of a semi detached where the porch continues on the other side to my neighbour.  I'm having trouble finding info on how hard a diy project this is?  Ideally I'd like to do mostly brick up to about waist level and then lots of window.

Has anyone here tried anything like this, that could possibly relate any tips to me?

Comment: Do you have any experience with brick laying, wall framing etc? This is a pretty complicated first effort DIY project.  Think you may need a mentor.

Comment: I've done framing for a couple of interior walls but not much brick work.

Answer (score 3):

1. You will need to dig a footing or be on an existing concrete slab. In the north (assuming your in the USA) the footing needs to extend below the frost line, which I'm told is 3 feet.
2. Cinder block is required for the first few feet (2 or 3 courses) of wall height to prevent water damage from rain or snow.
3. Anything that will change the outside appearance of the home will most certainly need a builders permit.
4. If this is your first project, you're going to need some help. There's a lot of skill sets required to do this.

Are you going to drywall the interior or leave the studs exposed? What about the exterior? Vinal siding? Stucco? etc... Any electrical in these walls? Windows?

There are kits available that'll make it easier, but at that rate, you may as well just have them install it.

[SunPorch](http://www.sunporch.com/)

I've wanted to do this to my house since I've moved in. Our porch is covered and on a concrete slab. I haven't decided yet if I want to use the space as a office or a first floor bathroom / laundry room. I put the expense around 7k to raise the floor to the same height as the house, drywall inside, playwood and vinal siding for the outside, and I'll reuse some of the windows and doors from the part of the house its attached to.

Nothing you can't do by yourself with another hand. Score some books from the local home store and plan it out. If you get stuck, make sure you know who to call.

Comment: Holy crap, that SunPorch seems way too expensive. The 12'x12' quote is ~$10k

Comment: Ok, obviously I needed to add some additional details, sorry, should have known that.

1) I'm actually in Toronto Canada, but shouldn't have to dig down any, the porch today is raised above 5 feet off the ground (you have to go up about 7 or 8 steps to get to up my front proch and to the front door).

2)  the porch is actually all done in cinderbloock up the height to the top of the stairs and the floor is concrete slab

Comment: 3) because the porch is already built and the roof done, literally all i'm doing is just enclosing it (framing the wall and doing the siding) and for the dimensions I listed above I don't need a permit in toronto (anything larger i would need one)

I wasn't allowed to post a picture originally because of rep points, but I'll post one now to give a better idea of what i'm starting with